# how do I scroll to bottom during a jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a little difficulty. I need my jquery script to load content, but for it to load at the bottom without the page bouncing from top to bottom like crazy.

Note: the content load works fine, I just want it to load always at bottom unless of course the user scrolls; I already have the scroll detection working, I just need help getting it to be default bottom.

here is my script:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
     $('#chatter').load('chat-panel.php');
}, 1500);
```

I need the scroll to be within the .load section to it remains at the bottom as default.

however my messages are stored in another div tag

```
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Also note that inside this tag is some php data that is gathered from a database which is the reason I left it blank.

This is the overall #chatter html:

```
<table style="<?php if(isset($_SESSION["chat"])) { echo "table-layout:fixed; max-height:445px; height: 445px;"; } else { echo "height:70%;"; }?> width: 80%;" align="center" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div id="chatter" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100;"><iframe id="sendit" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="message.php" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></td>      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is what loads inside the #chatter div (chat-panel.php):

```
<table style="height: 100%; max-height: 430px; width: 100%;" id="chattytable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" id="inc"><?php include("chat.php"); ?></td>
      <td width="20%" valign="top"><?php include("users.php"); ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The chat.php include contains the content for the:

```
<div id="messages"></div>
```

here is the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #messages {
        color: #514F4F;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: fit-content;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #31143d;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: #000000;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #562176;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background: #6a2075;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
  background: #73287b;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}
    #inc {
        text-align: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    #chat_wrap {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

I hope I explained the layout properly, please don't hesitate to ask if you get confused. All I ask is that you don't judge my coding, I am here to learn as much as you are :D

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
     //$('#chatter').load('chat-panel.php');
     $('#messages').append('New Message<br>');
       $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#messages').height()
  }, 500);
}, 1500);
```

[and here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qutmmvgd/)

Comment: One problem this: ` $('#chatter').load('chat-panel.php'); ` is a required element, that is what contains all of the code to load everything.

Comment: of course it's an exemple you remove this line $('#messages').append('New Message<br>'); and uncomment chatter

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try later.